# web hooks face books how to bypass a secure website

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token, webhooks

I am setting a webhooks for a Facebook application, and they required a call back url, this url must be in https

I do have a server with a call back website but it is not https, it is in http protocol

Any idea to bypass that? (work around? )

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to bypass it.
However, if you don't want to buy SSL certificate for your domain, you can configure your domain name with CloudFlare and use their [universal ssl](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-universal-ssl/).
I have used it with facebook webhooks and it works very well. It's free and very easy to configure.

The free plan allows you to use Flexible SSL. As per the [docs](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-Off-Flexible-SSL-Full-SSL-Full-SSL-Strict-mean-):

> Flexible SSL: secure connection between your visitor and CloudFlare, but no secure connection between CloudFlare and your web server. You don't need to have an SSL certificate on your web server, but your visitors still see the site as being HTTPS enabled.

Comment: I tried the website you've mentioned, and they told me this: `For your records, here are the CloudFlare name servers you've been assigned. dan.ns.cloudflare.com` but when i put `dan.ns.cloudflare.com` on the browser, i don't see my website. help please

Comment: These are the name servers assigned to your domain. Now, You need to login to your domain management portal and change the default name servers listed there to these name servers given by the cloudflare.